# Como saber quanto de armazenamento foi ocupado por um aplicativo Python/Django?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, django

Desenvolvi um aplicativo web com `Python` e `Django`. Gostaria de limitar a quantidade de espaço utilizada para cada usuário, pois na aplicação é possível inserir imagens e documentos.

Utilizo o Postgres como SGBD.

Como faço para saber a quantidade de armazenamento ocupada por um usuário em Python e Django?

Comment: Incluindo todo o overhead que o SGBD utiliza ou apenas os dados líquidos do usuário?

Comment: Os dois casos, o overhead e também os dados líquidos.

Comment: Comece a estudar por aqui: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage.html. Vai ter que estudar em profundidade.

Comment: Segundo a documentação do django, armazenar imagens no SGBD, não é uma boa ideia, Heim!

Comment: Estou armazenando apenas o endereço da imagem no SGBD @Sidon

Comment: Então pq a preocupação com espaço? se precisa se preocupar com isso ou tem algo errado ou o sistema é inviável. :-)

Comment: Pois como eu descrevi na pergunta, quero LIMITAR  o espaço de cada usuário que utiliza meu sistema. A não ser que você me forneça um servidor com espaço de armazenamento ilimitado e gratuito, aí sim se preocupar com o espaço é indispensável :-) @Sidon

Comment: Vc citou o SGBD, e o espaço ocupado por strings no SGBD é insignificante, não se deve limitar esse epaço e sim escalar, se necessário. Agora... se vc esta falando do espaço de armazenamento no File System, ai é outra estoria, as cotas de espaço por usuário devem ser determinada pelo admin da Infra e não pelo sua app e, finalmente, Se vc estiver armazenando artefatos do tipo imagem no mesmo FS em que faz deploy de sua app, sugiro repensar a estrategia, tb não é uma boa ideia.